# Scala: Tells me a class needs to be abstract

Tags: scala

I'm following the Scala class on coursera and in one of the videos the following code is used:

```
 abstract class IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet
}

class Empty extends IntSet {
  def contais(x: Int): Boolean = false
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = new NonEmpty(x, new Empty, new Empty)
  override def toString = "."
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet{
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean =
    if (x < elem) left contains x
    else if (x > elem) right contains x
    else true

  def incl(x: Int): IntSet =
    if (x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left incl x, right)
    else if (x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right incl x)
    else this

  override def toString = "{" + left + elem + right + "}"
}
```

The compiler tells me:

```
 "Error:(6, 8) class Empty needs to be abstract, since method contains
 in class IntSet of type (x: Int)Boolean is not defined class Empty
 extends IntSet {
       ^"
```

According to other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861776/scala-class-needs-to-be-abstract-since-method-is-not-defined-error) the problem usually has to do with a mismatch in the method signature, but in this case "contains" in **Empty** has exactly the same signature as the one in **IntSet**.

Comment: You have a typo, `contais` is missing an n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo:

```
class Empty extends IntSet {
  def contais(x: Int): Boolean = false
```

You typed `contais` instead of `contains`.

Comment: Shame on me... Sorry!